# How to construct a `std::string` from a buffer that may or may not contain a null?

Tags: c++, stdstring, null-terminated

I have a `char` buffer of known size (for simplicity, let's say a fixed-sized array) from which I would like to construct a `std::string`. The string in this buffer *may* be null-terminated or it may run up to and include the very last `char`. I wish to create a `std::string` containing the contents up to the first null byte *or* the end of the buffer, whichever comes first.

This seems like a common enough thing to want to do, but the solution is not immediately obvious to me while looking at the `std::string` API.

- `std::string` has a constructor taking a range via `const char *` and a length, but this constructor happily continues past null bytes and copies them into the string.
- Calling `std::strlen()` on the buffer before constructing the `string` is not an option as `strlen` requires the buffer to be null-terminated, which may not be the case.
- We could use the above constructor to make a `std::string` containing nulls and then resize it down to just before the first null, but that wastes memory as the `string` will be over-allocated.

What is the best and/or idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Normally the solution is to have your buffer get filled the same way.  Can you make your buffer 1 element larger then you could possibly want and make that last element null terminator so that you always have a null terminated buffer?

Comment: I am not making the buffer. It is being given to me by an API outside of my control. (The library in question is reading it directly from a binary file format which also stores it with a fixed length and optional null-termination.)

Answer (score 14):

The answer, as with so many questions regarding the C++ standard library, is to think about the problem in terms of iterators.

```
std::string stringFromBuffer(const auto & buffer)
{
    return std::string(std::begin(buffer),
                       std::find(std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer), '\0'));
}
```

`std::string` has a constructor taking two iterators, `first` and `last`. The `string` will be created by copying from `first` up until but not including `last`.

So `first` should obviously be the beginning of our buffer, while `last` should either be the first null in our buffer or one past the end of the buffer. Conveniently, that is exactly what a call to `std::find` searching the buffer for `'\0'` will return.

Comment: An easier way is to keep track of the end of the buffer, it's size. Then you can just use it directly in the construction of the string. This also allows a `std::string` object with arbitrary data, *including* the null-terminator embedded in the middle of the data. Also note that `std::begin` and `std::end` won't work if the `buffer` object doesn't support them, for example if you use a pointer.

Comment: I know the size of the buffer. That's not the issue. The issue is that I don't want the null values to end up in my `std::string`.

Comment: Do you have to actually copy the `char`s in the buffer at this stage or could you just create a `std::string_view` in the same way that you now create a `std::string`?

Comment: @ParkerCoates Using iterators is clean, but if you want to use sizes, then you would simply search the `buffer` for `'\0'` and if found then use its index as the new string length, otherwise use the `buffer`'s full size: `size_t str_size = ('\0' is found) ? (index of '\0') : (buffer size); return std::string(&buffer[0], str_size);`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way for an array of chars of known size. It's similar to Parker's answer but is just done in the constructor argument and is specific to the question of an array of chars.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  const char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}; // prints abcde
  // const char c[] = { 'a','b','\0','d','\0' };    // test alternate: prints ab
  // const char c[] = { 'a','b','\0','d','e' };     // test alternate: prints ab
  std::string s{c, std::find(c, c + sizeof c, '\0')};
  std::cout << s << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```